# OLAP Cube design issue - how to remove many to one relation

Tags: olap, many-to-one, star-schema

I had include my projectdetail in my previous question [OLAP Cube design issue for Telecommunication Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102752/olap-cube-design-issue-for-telecommunication-data). I had one question Is it necessary to remove one to many relationship on OLAP. What I heard is that OLAP should be able to give answer for zero dimension question, one dimension question and soon. Also I had several call detail on the same day so how can I design it in order to give answer of question What is the duration of call on day1? I'm not the best in shearing the problem so if any problem occurs in understanding the problem then please comment below.